# How to apply scaling to selected features, when using scaling in a pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following dataset(showing only first-five rows here):

```
     x0_Open Play   x1_Foot x1_Head  distance     angle
0        1             1       0     26.213579  14.213353
1        1             1       0     17.011103  20.424801
2        1             1       0     24.033554  13.163370
3        1             1       0     18.165922  21.541146
4        1             1       0     24.563994  16.868598
```

Here, the first three features are the result of `OneHotEncoder`. And now I want to scale the `distance` and `angle` using `StandardScaler`.

The general structure to code a pipeline in Python is as follows:

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

scaled_log_reg = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())
```

But this will scale the entire dataset, I just want to scale down `distance` and `angle` features. How can I implement this concept of performing scaling to particular features when applying scaling in a pipeline.

Comment: `ColumnTransformer`

Comment: Can you please explain or write an answer? It will definitely help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

```
scaler = ColumnTransformer([('scaler (or any name)', 
                              StandardScaler(),
                             ['distance', 'angle']
                            )], remainder='passthrough')
```

Answer (score 0):

- two features `features = ['distance','angle']`
- `X = dataframe[features]`

> when you do `StandardScaler().fit` at that time provide this two parameters features like this `StandardScaler().fit(X)`

hope this will help ;)

Comment: What if I want to apply a pipeline? A pipeline that would scale `distance` and `angle` and then use all the features (x0_Open Play, x1_Foot,  x1_Head, angle, distance) and perform logistic regression.